# Apollo graphql client query for list of results with dynamic size efficiently

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to solve the following problem with the Apollo graphql client in React:
I have a graphql server that allows queries for a list of results, for example search results. The total list is in-feasibly long so the result indices can be limited with a parameter:

```
query getResults($offset:Int!,$limit: Int!){
   getResults(offset:offset, limit: limit){ title, content}
}
```

When the user scrolls through the result list, I want to increase the limit parameter so that additional results are loaded. However doing this naively would force the server to resend all the results which were already loaded previously. Is there a way to solve the issue elegantly?